# Magento2 - How to reorder my account sidebar nav link?

Tags: magento2

How to reorder my account sidebar nav link  in `Magento2`

1. ACCOUNT DASHBOARD
2. MY ORDERS
3. ADDRESS BOOK
4. ACCOUNT INFORMATION
5. MY PRODUCT REVIEWS
6. NEWSLETTER SUBSCRIPTIONS

How to Re arrange the `nav` links.

Answer (score 0):

We can rearrange these links by using the "move" element in your layout file (customer_account.xml).

File path, if you are working in your custom theme: **app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{themename}/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml**

OR

File path, if you are working in your custom module:
 **app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml**

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="customer-account-navigation-account-edit-link" destination="customer_account_navigation" before="-"/>
        <move element="customer-account-navigation-orders-link" destination="customer_account_navigation" after="customer-account-navigation-account-edit-link"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

And the same with remain links you would like to sort. "customer-account-navigation-account-edit-link", "customer-account-navigation-orders-link" is the block name in layout, with the help of "before" and "after" element.